# "Attempt to assign property "weight" on null", exception: "Error",…}

Tags: laravel

Good Evening... New in Laravel and trying to develop web app for home business.
I am trying to Add new data on one table (`buffaloinspectiondata`) and update data on another table (`buffalodata`) using one Ajax.
For new data its working fine but for update in another table its giving error

> Attempt to assign property "weight" on null

Controller File

```php
public function addbuffaloinspectiondata(Request $req) 
{
    // add new data in buffaloinspection table for Buffalo ID

    $newdata = new buffaloinspectiondata;
    $newdata->buffaloID            = $req->buffaloID;
    $newdata->inspectiondate       = $req->inspectiondate;
    
    $newdata->weight               = $req->weight;
    $newdata->height               = $req->height;
    $newdata->pregnant             = $req->pregnantstatus;
    
    $newdata->health               = $req->healthstatus;
    $newdata->weeklytika           = $req->weeklytika;
    $newdata->monthlytika          = $req->monthlytika;
    
    $newdata->inspection           = $req->inspection;
    $newdata->inspectionby         = $req->inspectionby;
    $newdata->inspectionnote       = $req->inspectionnote;

    // Update data in buffalodata table for Buffalo ID
            
    $updatedata = buffalodata::find($req->buffaloID);

    $updatedata->weight             = $req->get('weight');
    $updatedata->height             = $req->get('height');
    $updatedata->pregnant           = $req->get('pregnantstatus');
    $updatedata->health             = $req->get('healthstatus');

    $newdata->save ();
    $updatedata->save ();

    return response()->json( $newdata,$updatedata );
}
```

AJAX Code =

```
$.ajaxSetup({     
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')} 
});

$(document).on('click', '#footer_addnewinspectiondata_button', function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/addbuffaloinspectiondata',
        data: {
            '_token'            : $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            'id'                : $('#fid').val(),
            'buffaloID'         : $('#buffaloID').val(),
            'inspectiondate'    : $('#inspectiondate').val(),
            'pregnantstatus'    : $('#pregnantstatus').val(),
            'healthstatus'      : $('#healthstatus').val(),
            'weight'            : $('#weight').val(),
            'height'            : $('#height').val(),
            'weeklytika'        : $('#weeklytika').val(),
            'monthlytika'       : $('#monthlytika').val(),
            'inspection'        : $('#inspection').val(),
            'inspectionby'      : $('#inspectionby').val(),
            'inspectionnote'    : $('#inspectionnote').val(),
        },
        success: function(data) {
                console.log (data)
              }
    });
});
```

Web.php

```
Route:: post('/addbuffaloinspectiondata', 
    [viewbuffaloController::class,'addbuffaloinspectiondata']);
```

Did i miss something..... Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your `$updatedata` variable is `null`, suggesting that the `find` method has not returned anything. Try doing a `dd($updatedata);` after `$updatedata = buffalodata::find($req->buffaloID);` to inspect its value then progress from there.

Comment: I try to make dd, but nothing shown in console. Programme run without any error but not update and add data done in table.. Can u explain how can i see dd in console

Comment: Try adding a failure handler to your `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to store each element because if you don't want to update one column the value is null
so try the following code is the example

```
 $updatedata = buffalodata::find($req->buffaloID);
    $weight = $request->weight;
    if($weight != null)
     $updatedata->weight = $weight; 
    $updatedata->save ();
```

and do this condition for each column

hopefully this help you

Comment: Will this work when (like in OPs case) `$updatedata` is `null`?

Comment: if he put the field required in migration its work

Comment: No it won't. The problem is that `$updatedata` is `null`, not `$weight`

Comment: should I delete my answer?

Comment: same error....Ossama Abd

Comment: The problem is that $updatedata is null...... how can i rectify this....@brombeer